# A subgraph relation from an algebraic identity

Tags: graph-theory, lattice-orders

Let $G_1, G_2$ and $G_3$ be undirected simple graphs such that $(G_1\cap G_2)\cup(G_2\cap G_3)\cup(G_1\cap G_3)=G_2$. How to show  that $G_1\subseteq G_2\subseteq G_3$?

Note that the graph's union $\cup$ and intersection $\cap$ act as lattice operations $\vee$ and $\wedge$, respectively. Also, $\cap$ distributes over $\cup$.

**Edited** Also, $G_1, G_2$ and $G_3$ have the same vertex set.

Comment: Why downvote? Is the question not clear? Or, is it not relevant to this forum? Kindly let me know the reason so that I may try again to present better.

Comment: For a concrete counterexample, let all three graphs have vertices $w,x,y,z$ and let $G_1$ have edges $wx,wy,xy$, let $G_2$ have edges $wy,xy,xz$, and let $G_3$ have edges $wz,xy,xz$.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but maybe some more context would help. Where did this come up? What makes you think it's true?

Comment: @bof Thanks for the help. By the ways, the converse is true i.e., if the relation holds then the equation.

Comment: @bof Well! It intuitively appeared to be true to me unless you provided with a counter example. It is clear now. Thank you. Such formulations are important because it is a sort of simplifying a Boolean functions or Boolean logic, where the elements are graphs.

Comment: Seeing as the left hand side of the equation is symmetric in $G_1$ and $G_3$, the conclusion should also have that symmetry. If $G_1\subseteq G_2\subseteq G_3$ were a valid conclusion, then $G_3\subseteq G_2\subseteq G_1$ would also be a valid conclusion, and therefore so would $G_1=G_2=G_3$.

Comment: Anyway, since there are only $3$ variables, drawing a Venn diagram would be an easy way to settle the question.

Comment: @bof Well! this conclusion helped me to settle my question the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to see that this cannot be true is to observe that your hypothesis does not change if you swap $G_1$ and $G_3$. Thus if your conjecture were true, it would not only imply $G_1 \subseteq G_2 \subseteq G_3$, but also $G_3 \subseteq G_2 \subseteq G_1$ and hence $G_1 = G_3$.